# Python cannot find shared library in cron

Tags: python, cron, shared-libraries

My Python script runs well in the shell. However when I cron it (under my own account) it gives me the following error:

**/usr/local/bin/python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

The first line of the script has:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
```

I know I have the following line in my ~/.bashrc file, which explains it works in the shell

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
```

If I cron it using the following it also works, but it looks ugly, and I hate to apply to every cron job.

```
00 * * * 1-5    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib && /path/somejob.py
```

Is there a better way to do it? I know our admin used to have an earlier version of Python installed on some shared nfs path, and it does not require any system level config change as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880454/python-executable-not-finding-libpython-shared-library). Our old Python script simply has this line as the first line no explicit setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

```
#!/nfs/apps/python/bin/python
```

In the old nfs installation

```
/nfs/apps/python/
  -- bin
  -- lib
  -- share
  -- include
```

Current Python is 2.7.3, and it is installed as follows: (Linux CentOS 6)

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-shared --with-system-expat --with-system-ffi
make
make install
```

**Update:**

1. As ansh0I suggested, adding LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the top of cronab works!
2. The reason python complained about the shared libraries is it is installed with **--enable-shared**. As a result the python binary file is much smaller, with much of the real interpreter code **shared** in /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so. Then you need to tell python where to find the shared library by setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH. If python is installed **without --enable-shared**, the binary file itself is much larger, and you don't need to specify any LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib` expression is working fine, you can set up environment variables at the top of the crontab file like below

```
#Setting up Environment variables
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib

#Here follow the cron jobs
* * * * *   echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH >> /home/user/logfile.log
* * * * *   some/cron/job.py
```