# SVN error when run by crontab

Tags: svn

I wrote a shell script to run svn, as following:

```
#! /bin/sh
cd /data/tmpsvn/
export LC_ALL=zh_CN.utf8
date "+getSvn - [%Y-%m-%d %T]" >>svn.log 2>&1
/usr/local/bin/svn checkout http://IP >> svn.log 2>&1
```

Then I wrote a crontab:

```
*/5 * * * * sh /data/htdocs/zlbz-test/tools/get_svn_all.sh 1>/dev/null 2>&1
```

Some errors occur like this shown in log file:

```
getSvn - [2015-05-12 14:40:01]
/usr/local/bin/svn: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

but when I execute this command in terminal, it work well.

Can any people explain what has happened?

---

It's been solve according to Vadim Landa's link in the comment.
I added a line in the script:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/openssl/lib/
```

Comment: @VadimLanda, add your comment as an answer please so I may upvote it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably, the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable is only set in your shell profile, but not in the crontab. Check out this thread: [Python cannot find shared library in cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452908/python-cannot-find-shared-library-in-cron)