# libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, shared-libraries

I have trying to run python script from the terminal but getting the next error message :

```
ImportError: libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

if I run print sys.version I get :

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.version
2.7.3 (default, Feb 26 2013, 16:27:39)
[GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)]
```

and if I run ldd /usr/local/bin/python

```
>> ldd /usr/local/bin/python
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff219ff000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003300c00000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x0000003300800000)
        libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x0000003310e00000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003300000000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003300400000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00000032ffc00000)
```

I don't understand which python do I have ? why running this python script from the terminal is failing ?
I have tried to run

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/
```

with no luck...

BTW - I have managed to debug this script in eclipse with the python plug-in, and when I look at the debug configuration I see that the PYTHONPATH is set for :

```
/..../eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_3.1.0.201312121632/pysrc/pydev_sitecustomize:/..../workspace/style_checker/src:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg:/usr/local/lib/python2.7:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

so eclipse manage somehow to find this python2.7 libs... so how can I do it with out eclipse and from the command line ? what am I doing wrong ? using CentOS6.

Comment: Have you tried `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?
In my case, I ran `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/minh.lengoc/.local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Answer (score 55):

Try to find file `libpython2.7.so.1.0`:

`locate libpython2.7.so.1.0`

In my case, it show out put:

`/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0`

Then paste line `/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64` to file `/etc/ld.so.conf`

And run `ldconfig`.
It solved my problem. Goodluck!

Comment: Okay, how to include that? Just pasting the path in the text file? I tried that it did not work. Any other way?

Comment: @ krozaine: Can you paste the output of command `locate libpython2.7.so.1.0` and content of file `/etc/ld.so.conf` ?

Comment: I'm curious why this isn't handled by the python2.7 rpm installation?  It seems like a packaging oversight?

Comment: libpython2.7.so.1.0 does not exist on my system. $ python -V ... 2.7.12

Comment: -- You can use `whereis libpython2.7.so.1.0` to locate the file. :)

Comment: @atb00ker `whereis` did not yield any results for me, but `locate` did.

Answer (score 32):

For some reason these two have worked perfectly for me:

```sh
apt-get install libpython2.7
sudo apt-get install libatlas3-base
```

I found them [here](https://github.com/pypa/manylinux/issues/30) and [here](http://danielnouri.org/notes/2012/12/19/libblas-and-liblapack-issues-and-speed,-with-scipy-and-ubuntu/)

Comment: Just installing libpython2.7 did it

Comment: Only "apt-get install libpython2.7"   is worked. No needed to install others

Answer (score 4):

For me, the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1100297/3559967 worked.
The author of that question also stated that the LD_LIBRARY_PATH approach did not work for him, but adding the library path to `/etc/ld.so.conf` and running `ldconfig` worked.

Answer (score 3):

I was having a similar issue while executing a 32 bits gdb binary on a 64 bits Linux:

```
arm-eabi-gdb: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

and I solved it by installing `libpython2.7:i386` (note the :i386 suffix)

Comment: Me too. Work with *Ubuntu 20.04 x86-64

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a subject I'm keen on, but my understanding is for Linux machines especially (where you're compiling python binaries) that [shared library directories should be specified at the compile step](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26657830/1080804).

For instance, following the linked example, here is how I ensure `libpython2.7.so.1.0` is included *in addition* to other libraries:

```
./configure --enable-shared \
        --prefix=/directory/for/Python-2.7.15 \
        LDFLAGS="-Wl,--rpath=/usr/local/lib -Wl,--rpath=/directory/for/Python-2.7.15"
```

Notice I'm also installing python to a fixed directory of my choosing, via the `--prefix` option. That might not be necessary for you, but I did it to provide a solution for the general case where your python install might be located *anywhere*.

With the above solution, I never have to export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or mess with `ldconfig`

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${WORK_PATH}/venv/lib".

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the Correct answer:

Multiple question on how to the following :
Then paste line /opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64 to file /etc/ld.so.conf

The correct way to do this add a new file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/, and add the line above in that file.