# Missing libpython2.7.so.1.0 on Python 2.7.13 Heroku dynos

Tags: python, heroku, google-cloud-debugger

We are running our Python 2.7.13 application on Heroku.

I believe recently Heroku has changed Python runtime defaults from 2.7.13 to 3.6.1 for new application.

So we put `python-2.7.13` to `runtime.txt` file as they recommend but now if we create a new Heroku app and deploy out code to it, it complains that `libpython2.7.so.1.0` cannot be found.

Heroku log content:

`...
2017-06-30T10:56:05.825667+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleclouddebugger/capture_collector.py", line 30, in <module>
2017-06-30T10:56:05.825694+00:00 app[web.1]:     import cdbg_native as native
2017-06-30T10:56:05.825725+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

We also cannot find `libpython2.7.so.1.0` on dynos, `heroku run "cd /; find | grep libpython2.7.so.1.0"` gives nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to the solution presented in the reply to the [libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20842732/libpython2-7-so-1-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory). [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20842732/libpython2-7-so-1-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory) "Try to find file libpython2.7.so.1.0: locate libpython2.7.so.1.0 In my case, it show out put: `/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0` Then add dir `/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64 to file /etc/ld.so.conf` And run ldconfig".