# error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.7.so.1.0 when making virtual env in ubuntu

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, virtualenv

I use anaconda2. After I install virtualenv by run `pip install virtualenv`. when I run `virtualenv test`. It shows error:

```
New python executable in /home/ztgong/work/virtenvs/test/bin/python
/home/ztgong/work/virtenvs/test/bin/python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ERROR: The executable /home/ztgong/work/virtenvs/test/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is u'/home/ztgong/work/virtenvs' (should be u'/home/ztgong/work/virtenvs/test')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

what causes this problem?
can anyone give some advises?

Comment: Can you try with "-p" option? Example `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 (or /usr/bin/python) test`?

Comment: you mean using '/usr/bin/python'? It indeed works, but why can not use python of my local anaconda2

Answer (score 0):

Might be late for this question, but solution present [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35623092/9630273) worked for me.

1. Try to find file libpython2.7.so.1.0

   find / -name libpython2.7.so.1.0
2. Then add the resultant directory in file /etc/ld.so.conf.
   Simply write the directory name into this file.
3. Run Command ldconfig