# libpython2.7.20.1.0 not found while installing g++ 4.8

Tags: g++, g++4.8

I'm trying to upgrade my Centos6 system to g++ 4.8 using the following commands:

```
$ wget http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-2/devtools-2.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/devtools-2.repo
$ yum install devtoolset-2-gcc devtoolset-2-binutils
$ yum install devtoolset-2-gcc-c++ devtoolset-2-gcc-gfortran
```

However I get an error on step 2:

```
 #  yum install devtoolset-2-gcc devtoolset-2-binutils
 /usr/bin/python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've installed anaconda 4.4 and am running Python 3.6 from my Anaconda path.  I'm not sure why I'm seeing this error when trying to upgrade g++.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20842732/libpython2-7-so-1-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory) solved the generalized problem of not seeing libpython2.7.so.1.0, but it is answer a different question.

Is the etiquette to mark this answer as some sort of duplicate, or do I point this answer to that answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit `/etc/ld.so.conf` and run `ldconfig` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20842732/libpython2-7-so-1-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory).