# Error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.7.so.1.0

Tags: python-2.7, conda

Since a few days I get the following error when I try to open python that was installed with conda. The only thing that changed is that I changed the group of the files located in /software and gave the group read and write writes.

```
/software/local/share/bcbio/anaconda/bin/python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried many different things. I first look at the output of `ldd`

```
ldd /software/local/share/bcbio/anaconda/bin/python
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd11bfc000)
    libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /software/local/share/bcbio/anaconda/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007f276fa9b000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00000036be600000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00000033bd800000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00000033bec00000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00000033be000000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00000033bd400000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00000033bd000000)
```

And looked at the permission of the librarie, which seemed to be correct:

```
ls -lah /software/local/share/bcbio/anaconda/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
-rwxrwsr-x+ 1 vsc lp_neuro 7.7M Jun  7  2018 /software/local/share/bcbio/anaconda/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
```

I also tried to export different environment variables:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/software/local/share/bcbio/anaconda/bin/../lib/;

export PYTHONHOME=/software/local/share/bcbio/anaconda/bin/../lib/;

export PYTHONPATH=/software/local/share/bcbio/anaconda/bin/../lib/;
```

Since it is a conda installation of python, solutions needing root access (which I do not have) are of no uses. E.g. editing /etc/ld.so.conf is no option for me.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: Pls see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20842732/libpython2-7-so-1-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20842732/libpython2-7-so-1-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: @newkid I forgot to mention that I do not have root access on this machine so editing /etc/ld.so.conf is no option.

Comment: In the end I just reinstalled everything, which solved the problem, but still not sure what caused the issue.