# Python can't find libpython2,7.so even with LD_LIBRARY_PATH set

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a tool that uses Python 2.7.6 but it keeps returning the same error message:

```
python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I see that people have had this problem before, but it seems that the advice is to export to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and I don't think this is the problem here (as shown below):

ldd 'which python' gives:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff19ac0000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x000000360c200000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x000000360be00000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x000000361ce00000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x000000360ce00000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x000000360ba00000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000000360b600000)
```

`echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` 
contains the folder `/software/src/Python-2.7.6`

`ls  /software/src/Python-2.7.6 | grep libpython2.7`

gives:

```
libpython2.7.a
libpython2.7.so
libpython2.7.so.1.0
```

Is there something in the configuration of my python installation that is wrong here?

Comment: Check it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880454/python-executable-not-finding-libpython-shared-library

Comment: Like i wrote, exporting to LD_LIBRARY_PATH does not work somehow. LD_LIBRARY_PATH contains a folder that in turn contains the libpython files needed. Still somehow it's not working.

Comment: Check it again, I believe my answer will help you since it looks like you're compiling from source.

Comment: I have a simliar problem LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set ,but ld could not find unless I use ld -LXXXX -liomp5 for example, simply ld -liomp5 does not work