# error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.6.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, python-2.6

I have installed python2.6(initially through apt-get and then uninstall and reinstalling through source) in ubuntu 12.04 (python2.7 being the default version installed).

The ***ldconfig -p | grep python*** command yields the following results

```
libpython2.7.so.1.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
libpyglib-2.0-python2.7.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libpyglib-2.0-python2.7.so.0
libpyglib-gi-2.0-python2.7.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libpyglib-gi-2.0-python2.7.so.0
libpyglib-gi-2.0-python2.7.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libpyglib-gi-2.0-python2.7.so
```

The libpython2.6.so.1.0 seems to be missing.
This is important as i am trying to run uwsgi 1.0.3 
which is throwing the following error :

```
error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.6.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

After going through numerous threads on the same matter such as :

[Python executable not finding libpython shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880454/python-executable-not-finding-libpython-shared-library)
Where we set the *LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib /usr/local/bin/python* it still failed in finding the respective file

Any help on the matter will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: where and how did you `LD_LIBRARY_PATH...`, also I ave python2.6 installed and there is no `libpython2.6.so.1.0`, why not use pyenv?

Comment: I think you should seriously consider just using the system's Python 2.7, or at least 2.6 from apt-get rather than building from source.  You can sidestep these issues easily.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I tried doing the same using pyenv but to no avail

Comment: @JohnZwinck I'm am setting up a legacy system for some debugging and hence i would try to replicate it as of now