# Manually built python 2.7.10 on GNU/Linux loads .so of old python2.7.6 installed from packages

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ubuntu, linux-mint

I've successfully built from sources and installed python version 2.7.10 into folder /usr/local. And then I have executed /usr/local/bin/python and it has shown that it has version 2.7.6. Which is not correct. Trying to find out what is wrong, I've run ldd /usr/local/bin/python and got the following:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffd5fe4000)
    libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007f2c006f8000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f2c004da000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2c00115000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f2bffefc000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f2bffcf8000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f2bffaf5000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f2bff7ef000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2c00c5c000)
```

Which means that manually built python 2.7.10 loads *.so library of python 2.7.6, which was installed by default package manager. Could you help to find out why this happens?

Configuring have been done by the following commands:

./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-shared

I am using Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela KDE edition, which is based on Ubuntu 14.04.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of that is the algorithm linux uses to select the shared object to load.  This procedure allows several versions of the same library to coexist without problem in the same system.  Sometimes, something has to be touched first to force it to select an alternative, as now for you.

I'll explain first the algorithm and then the solution in your case:

First linux has a binary database indexed by `soname`(this is a name the dynamic linker uses to select the proper library version)  It enters with the so called `soname` in the library (embedded in the application when it was linked) and gets a file (normally the filename is `/usr/lib/`*soname*)  the database is constructed by searching a directory list (configured in `/etc/ld.so.conf`) for all libraries, extracting their `soname`s, and indexing from soname to actual file.  For it to work quickly, libraries have a symbolic link to the soname, *and this is the reason you link to the wrong library*, the link points to the old version.

The rest is easy.  You'll find a library, for example `/usr/lib/libfoo.so.1` (in this case the soname is `libfoo.so.1`) that has two versions, `/usr/lib/libfoo.so.1.3` and `/usr/lib/libfoo.so.1.4`, and **a symbolic link** `/usr/lib/libfoo.so.1 -> /usr/lib/libfoo.so.1.3`.  You have to remove this link and construct the right one.

```
rm -f /usr/lib/libfoo.so.1
ln -s libfoo.so.1.3 /usr/lib/libfoo.so.1
```

After that, it would be nice to reconstruct (I think it's not necessary, as you have it installed, but doesn't hurt) the database with

```
/sbin/ldconfig
```

If you run it with `-l` it will show you all the shared libs it has in the database.  Try `ldconfig(8)`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I've already solved problem. I've just added /usr/local/lib to $LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Your solution have to work as well. But here rpath seems to be libpython2.7.so.1.0 not libpython2.7.so.1, so if i would make your way i had to delete original so file, not symlink. Therefore in my case adding to LD_LIBRARY_PATH is preferable. Only after i solved the problem i found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880454/python-executable-not-finding-libpython-shared-library

Comment: You can add it also to `/etc/ld.so.conf` file and make it unnecessary to use that environment variable always in your processes.  Remember to call `ldconfig(8)` after adding the directory to that file.

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved by adding /usr/local to $LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Other variants of solution are here [Python executable not finding libpython shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880454/python-executable-not-finding-libpython-shared-library)

Comment: I would much rather recommend [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26657830/3303940) answer from the same question instead - setting the `rpath` during compile time is usually a lot cleaner solution. It ensures correct library search path for the python binaries, without having to make a system-wide modification (`/etc/ld.so.conf`), or setting an environment variable.