# Fixing/Adding symlink

Tags: python, python-2.7, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to compile mod_wsgi for use with python2.7 on my centos 6.6 server.

I've downloaded the source code and ran the following command -

```
./configure --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7 --disable-framework
```

Which ran fine.  However, when I try to run `make` I get the following -

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
.
make: *** [src/server/mod_wsgi.la] Error 1
```

edit - I ran the following command and my Python2.7 is 64 bit -

```
import struct
print struct.calcsize("P") * 8
```

I also tried doing a pip2.7 install mod_wsgi and I get the following -

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
    /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

In reading the documenation here -

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues#Lack_Of_Python_Shared_Library

It would seem I have an issue with my symlinks.  How would I go about creating or replacing the symlink they're referencing here -

```
If the version of Python being used was compiled for X86 64 bit architecture and a shared library does exist, but not in the 'config' directory, then adding the missing symlink may be all that is required.
```

I've confirmed the Python2.7 is a 64 bit install and I ran the following to configure it so it is indeed a shared environment -

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-unicode=ucs4 --enable-shared LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib"
make && make altinstall
```

Comment: I had to re-compile my install of python2.7 as per this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880454/python-executable-not-finding-libpython-shared-library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to recompile my Python as found in the following documentation -

[Python executable not finding libpython shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880454/python-executable-not-finding-libpython-shared-library)

After that I was able to use the 64bit version of mod-wsgi.