# Can't import cartopy

Tags: python, cartopy

Getting this error when I try to import cartopy: `ImportError: libproj.so.25: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

cartopy requires PROJ 8.0.0 or higher and I have PROJ 9.0.0 installed. `proj` is at `/usr/local/lib`, and I tried adding the path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH by running the shell command: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib`

All the other dependencies specified [here](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/installing.html) are satisfied.

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Python version: 3.8

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: https://github.com/conda-forge/cartopy-feedstock/issues/93

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40071541/python-import-error-cannot-open-shared-object-file

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: I had this error after building `proj-9.0.0` from source as part of a Docker build. The solution for me was to copy the contents of build/lib to `/usr/lib`. `RUN cp -a /proj-9.0.0/build/lib/. /usr/lib/`

That worked.