# How do I enable python35 from Software Collections at login?

Tags: rhel7, software-collections

I followed the [Software Collections Quick Start](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/docs/) and I now have Python 3.5 installed. How can I make it always enabled in my `~/.bashrc`, so that I do not have to enable it manually with `scl enable rh-python35 bash`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `scl_source` feature.

Create a new file in `/etc/profile.d/` to enable your collection automatically on start up:

```
$ cat /etc/profile.d/enablepython35.sh
#!/bin/bash
source scl_source enable python35
```

See [How can I make a Red Hat Software Collection persist after a reboot/logout?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/527703) for background and details.

Comment: I believe that this is the best answer. Unfortunately, that page hides the solution and is inaccessible to someone without a RedHat account. The above appears to only be part of the answer. Additionally, some special package appears to be needed for the solution above to work.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the answer is complete. The package required is 'scl-utils'.

Comment: I ran into an issue when trying to use it in a container, which led me to believe that the answer was incomplete. I'll check and see if I'm using scl-utils in the dockerfile.

Comment: This KB article is now accessible to the public without an account, from what I see.

Comment: This is the link I was referring to as being inaccessible to someone without RedHat account:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=874417
It appears to still be unavailable to someone without a redhat account. ... With that said, though, I don't need to access that link to understand the solution. I guess I was just having trouble reading that day.

Comment: Adding `source scl_source enable python3*` to `~/.bash_profile` worked for me on CentOS 6.9.

Answer (score 1):

This answer would be helpful to those who have limited auth access on the server.

I had a similar problem for `python3.5` in HostGator's shared hosting. `Python3.5` had to be enabled every single damn time after login. Here are my 10 steps for the resolution:

1. Enable the python through scl script `python_enable_3.5` or `scl enable rh-python35 bash`.
2. Verify that it's enabled by executing `python3.5 --version`. This should give you your python version.
3. Execute `which python3.5` to get its path. In my case, it was `/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/bin/python3.5`. You can use this path to get the version again (just to verify that this path is working for you.)
4. Awesome, now please `exit` out of the current shell of `scl`.
5. Now, lets get the version again through this complete python3.5 path `/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/bin/python3.5 --version`.

   It won't give you the version but an error. In my case, it was

```sh
/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/bin/python3.5: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.5m.so.rh-python35-1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

6. As mentioned in [Tamas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7880519/1957036), we gotta find that `so` file. `locate` doesn't work in shared hosting and you can't install that too.

   Use the following command to find where that file is located:

```sh
find /opt/rh/rh-python35 -name "libpython3.5m.so.rh-python35-1.0"
```

7. Above command would print the complete path (second line) of the file once located. In my case, output was

```sh
find: `/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/root': Permission denied
/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64/libpython3.5m.so.rh-python35-1.0
```

8. Here is the complete command for the python3.5 to work in such shared hosting which would give the version,

```sh
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64 /opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/bin/python3.5 --version
```

9. Finally, for shorthand, append the following alias in your ~/.bashrc

```sh
alias python351='LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64 /opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/bin/python3.5'
```

10. For verification, reload the `.bashrc` by `source ~/.bashrc` and execute `python351 --version`.

Well, there you go, now whenever you login again, you have got `python351` to welcome you.

This is not just limited to `python3.5`, but can be helpful in case of other `scl` installed softwares.

Comment: Can't you simply put `source scl_source enable python35` into your `.bashrc` and be done?

Comment: Tried.My bash got stuck and had to use ftp to reset the `.bashrc`

Comment: Wait So I can install python3 on Hostgator shared hosting? I though you can only install python2 ! Would you care to explain how did you install it ?

Comment: @IsaacWassouf Hostgator has the [instruction](https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/what-software-and-program-versions-does-hostgator-offer) for that too (search for `rh-python35` in webpage). Its exactly as how @user7610 said. Add `source scl_source enable rh-python35` in `.bashrc` file. It didn't work for me first few times, so I had to follow all above steps in the answer. I hope single line works for you on your first time. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It worked by just adding `source scl_source enable rh-python35` in `.bashrc` as you mentioned! By any chance do you have any idea of how to deploy a Django app in shared hosting? All the tutorials I've seen require using the "Setup Python app" under the Software section which is not supported in shared hosting as I understood from customer service