# Pyinstaller saying I am missing libraries

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

```
OSError: Python library not found: libpython3.8m.dll, libpython3.8.dll, python38.dll, libpython38m.dll, libpython38.dll
    This would mean your Python installation doesn't come with proper library files.
    This usually happens by missing development package, or unsuitable build parameters of Python installation.
```

How do I solve this issue? I am trying to compile my stock market simulator into an exe but I keep on getting this issue. I have tried various solutions, but all of them have no worked.

Comment: If you read the error message it is saying that your Python installation needs attention.

Comment: how can i fix my python installation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pyinstaller error: OSError: Python library not found: libpython3.4mu.so.1.0, libpython3.4m.so.1.0, libpython3.4.so.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067039/pyinstaller-error-oserror-python-library-not-found-libpython3-4mu-so-1-0-lib)